# iframe conflicting with hammer.js gestures

Tags: javascript, iframe, touch, hammer.js

I'm using hammer.js [the jQuery plugin version] to provide simple touch gestures – in this case, I'm just using swipeleft and swiperight – to navigate between pages. All works good, except...

On some pages I have an `<iframe>` to display a Youtube video. When the gesture begins within the `<iframe>`, the javascript to load the next page doesn't run, as the context is the `<iframe>`, not the rest of the page. If the gesture begins anywhere else on the page [even if it ends in the `<iframe>`] the next page loads properly.

What I want to have happen is for the gesture to be recognized anywhere in the window, and not be affected by the iframe.

I've done a fair amount of googling, but I've yet to come up with a working solution.

Here is my Hammer JS code:

```
var hammertime = Hammer('html').on("swipeleft", function(event) {
  document.location = "http://www.example.com/";
});
```

And, here is the standard YouTube `<iframe>` code:

```
<iframe width="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Gh5XWWXHVQk?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I'm also a bit of a JS newbie.

Any help that you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Ryan

Comment: Feels like a bit of a cheat, but you could position an invisible element over the player, this would stop the youtube buttons working though. I think the issue is that hammer isn't running from inside the iframe and the browser treats it like two seperate pages. I'm in no way an expert on how browsers work with iframes and I've never used hammer (although will now be checking it out) but I doubt there is a perfect solution for you right now. :(

Comment: @JamieTaylor – I did come across a similar problem that suggested doing just that, but it was for dragging an object over the iframe, and they only created the object during the drag. I thought that was the answer until I realized that they could do that because their action starts outside of the iframe. And, as you say, the element would stop the youtube buttons from working, which isn't ideal either. Currently, I'm considering changing my way of including YouTube videos, perhaps using MediaElements.js, but, again, not necessarily ideal...

Comment: Just tried out MediaElement.js, and it doesn't solve this, as MediaElement.js inserts an iframe...

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar requirement, and what I did was attach my swipe events to the iframes `<body>`  like this:

```
// Get <iFrame>
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeElement');

iframe.onload = function () {
    // Once content is available, get body
    var iframeBody = iframe.contentWindow.document.body;

    // Register gestures as normal
    Hammer(iframeBody).on("swipeleft", function (event) {
        // Dosomething
        SwipeLeft();
    });
}
```

The onload ensures that the document has finished loading and the element you want is available for binding.

Now swiping left anywhere in the iframe will trigger SwipeLeft(), you could couple this with bindings on the main document to achieve a 'full screen' swipe.