# Vimeo embed and Hammer.js conflict

Tags: javascript, video, vimeo, gestures

For the website I'm making I want to use swipe left and swipe right to go to either the next or previous page. For this I use Hammer.js and it works fine expect on the Vimeo embed. I tried the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24803222/1641903) but couldn't get it to work.

For reference: This is the vimeo embed code:

```
<iframe id="vimeo" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/152562657" width="1024" height="576" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The Hammer.js code I normally use:

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('vimeo');
var mc = new Hammer(myElement);
mc.on("swipeleft swiperight", function(ev) {
    window.location = "http://google.nl";
});
```

What I also tried based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24803222/1641903):

```
 var iframe = document.getElementById('vimeo');

 iframe.onload = function () {
   var iframeBody = iframe.contentWindow.document.body;
   iframeBody.on("swipeleft swiperight", function(ev) {
      window.location = "http://google.nl";
   });
}
```

Comment: I also have the same problem, did you find a workaround?